# GRUB fails boot with "no such device"... sometimes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, linux-mint

I've recently updated Linux Mint from Rosa to Sarah. Ever since that, booting my system *sometimes* ends up with GRUB telling my that there is no such device and putting me into rescue mode. After that, shutting the system off by way of the power button and then turning it on again has always resulted in my system booting the way I'd expect it to.

So that's what distinguishes this from all the other "GRUB started in rescue mode" posts (that I could find): it doesn't happen on a regular basis (albeit frequently). Also, I haven't encountered a problem like this ever before, which makes me hope that this isn't related to hardware failure (since that would mean that the hardware failure must have coincided with me updating Mint).

**[edit / update]:** Some more information about my system.

Installed are two SSDs, one of them (`sda`) containing a Windows 7 installation and the other (`sdb`) the aforementioned Linux Mint. The latter is encrypted using the *Default Encryption Method Advertised in the Installer™*.

Output of `fdisk -l`:

```
[... some stuff about /dev/ramX ...]

Disk /dev/sda: 447.1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe8e30d86

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       718848 937699327 936980480 446.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0003e0ae

Device     Boot  Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1         2048     499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       501758 1000214527 999712770 476.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       501760 1000214527 999712768 476.7G 83 Linux

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/mapper/sdb5_crypt: 476.7 GiB, 511850840064 bytes, 999708672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root: 460.9 GiB, 494814625792 bytes, 966434816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1: 15.8 GiB, 16982736896 bytes, 33169408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

This is the first time I noticed the `Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.` message, but I don't know what to make of it.

Another thing I've noticed is a certain regularity in the appearance of the GRUB rescue mode; it almost exclusively happens when I boot up the system after it's been turned off overnight.

Comment: What is your system's configuration?

Comment: Very sorry for the late reply. I added some more details.

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed it by **disabling "Fast Boot" in BIOS** settings

I had the same issue with dual boot (Win 10/Ubuntu ) with GRUB reporting "no such device" when shutting down from Ubuntu

Some also recommend disabling Secure Boot but i didn't have that enabled here